# Change the foreground color for combobox in netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I want to change the color of text inside combobox in netbaeans>>
I changed it from combobox properties but the change not appear when I run my application.
The checkbox and other swing controls take the change Properly.
I try it with eclipse IDE but I have the same problem

Comment: What combobox are you reffering to?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html  > You can see the Previous site>> I want to change the color of the text inside the combobox

Comment: This isn't a IDE-related issue. Doesn't matter if you use NetBeans or Eclipse. Plus, the solution is adding a cell renderer, which is explained in the link you've provided.